# making a query efficient

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the following query in mysql for a reporting tool.

It is a inline select.The query gives me correct result but takes a long time to run. Can someone suggest any alternate way or writing the query to make it more efficient.

```
SELECT z.name1, (
       SELECT COUNT( AES_DECRYPT( l.answertext,  "aaa" ) ) 
       FROM household_data l
       INNER JOIN sms_household m 
             ON l.prim_key = m.hhid
       INNER JOIN sms_psu n 
             ON n.psu = m.psu
             AND n.state = m.state
             AND n.district = m.district
       INNER JOIN (
             SELECT p.prim_key, p.fieldname
             FROM household_data p
             WHERE p.basicname =  'Q05'
             AND AES_DECRYPT( p.answertext,  "aaa" ) =2
       ) women 
             ON l.prim_key = women.prim_key
             AND SUBSTR( l.fieldname, 5, 1 ) = SUBSTR( women.fieldname, 5, 1 ) 
             WHERE l.basicname =  'Q08' AND AES_DECRYPT( l.answertext,  "aaa" ) = 14
             AND z.psu = n.psu
             [AND n.state IN ( {state} )] 
             [AND n.district IN ( {district} )]
) female14, (
       SELECT COUNT( AES_DECRYPT( l.answertext,  "aaa" ) ) 
       FROM household_data l
       INNER JOIN sms_household m ON l.prim_key = m.hhid
       INNER JOIN sms_psu n 
             ON n.psu = m.psu
             AND n.state = m.state
             AND n.district = m.district
       INNER JOIN (
             SELECT p.prim_key, p.fieldname
             FROM household_data p
             WHERE p.basicname =  'Q05'
             AND AES_DECRYPT( p.answertext,  "aaa" ) =2
       ) women 
             ON l.prim_key = women.prim_key
             AND SUBSTR( l.fieldname, 5, 1 ) = SUBSTR( women.fieldname, 5, 1 ) 
             WHERE l.basicname =  'Q08' AND AES_DECRYPT( l.answertext,  "aaa" ) = 15
             AND z.psu = n.psu
             [AND n.state IN ( {state} )] 
             [AND n.district IN ( {district} )]
) female15, (
       SELECT COUNT( AES_DECRYPT( l.answertext,  "aaa" ) ) 
       FROM household_data l
       INNER JOIN sms_household m 
             ON l.prim_key = m.hhid
       INNER JOIN sms_psu n 
             ON n.psu = m.psu
                    AND n.state = m.state
                           AND n.district = m.district
       INNER JOIN (
             SELECT p.prim_key, p.fieldname
             FROM household_data p
             WHERE p.basicname =  'Q05'
             AND AES_DECRYPT( p.answertext,  "aaa" ) =2
       ) women 
             ON l.prim_key = women.prim_key
             AND SUBSTR( l.fieldname, 5, 1 ) = SUBSTR( women.fieldname, 5, 1 ) 
       WHERE l.basicname =  'Q08' AND AES_DECRYPT( l.answertext,  "aaa" ) =16
       AND z.psu = n.psu
       [AND n.state IN ( {state} )] 
       [AND n.district IN ( {district} )]
) female16, (
       SELECT count(AES_DECRYPT(household_data.answertext , "aaa")) * 100 / (
              SELECT count(AES_DECRYPT(household_data.answertext , "aaa"))
              FROM household_data 
              INNER JOIN sms_household
              INNER JOIN sms_psu
                    ON sms_psu.psu = sms_household.psu
                    AND sms_psu.state = sms_household.state
                    AND sms_psu.district = sms_household.district
              WHERE  basicname = 'Q07_year' AND z.psu= sms_psu.psu
              [AND sms_psu.state IN ( {state} )] 
              [AND sms_psu.district IN ( {district} )]
              )
       FROM household_data 
       INNER JOIN sms_household
       INNER JOIN sms_psu
             ON sms_psu.psu = sms_household.psu
             AND sms_psu.state = sms_household.state
             AND sms_psu.district = sms_household.district
       WHERE AES_DECRYPT(household_data.answertext , "aaa") = 9998 
       AND basicname = 'Q07_year'
       AND z.psu = sms_psu.psu
       [AND sms_psu.state IN ( {state} )] 
       [AND sms_psu.district IN ( {district} )]
) PercYearDontKnow
FROM household_data x
INNER JOIN sms_household y 
      ON x.prim_key = y.hhid
INNER JOIN sms_psu z 
      ON y.psu = z.psu
AND z.state = y.state
AND z.district = y.district
WHERE 1=1 
[AND y.state IN ( {state} )] 
[AND y.district IN ( {district} )
GROUP BY z.psu
```

Comment: eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeek!

Comment: can you post your schema and what exactly are you trying to achieve? That code is pretty much unreadable...

Comment: No wonder it takes too much time .... Read about sql query optimization techniques!!!

Comment: Add indexes for key fields in the DB vastly improves JOIN syntax in my opinion.

Comment: What is the `COUNT( AES_DECRYPT( l.answertext,  "aaa" ) )` supposed to count?

Comment: Thanks every1 for the suggestion.

Comment: @edze , each inline select is seperate query.The where clause changes slightly.

Comment: @ypercube, I wanted to count the number of rows fetched. I have modified the count to count(*) as suggested by Gustav Bertram

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your post to make your query structure more clear. I suggest that you do the same in your own code.

After the restructure, it becomes clear that you are repeating some of your query to find female14, female15 and female16.

Maybe you should make a separate query for that part, like this:

```
   SELECT n.name1, 
          n.psu, 
          AES_DECRYPT( l.answertext,  "aaa" ) AS answer, 
          COUNT(*) as count
   FROM household_data l
   INNER JOIN sms_household m 
         ON l.prim_key = m.hhid
   INNER JOIN sms_psu n 
         ON n.psu = m.psu
         AND n.state = m.state
         AND n.district = m.district
   INNER JOIN (
         SELECT p.prim_key, p.fieldname
         FROM household_data p
         WHERE p.basicname =  'Q05'
         AND AES_DECRYPT( p.answertext,  "aaa" ) =2
   ) women 
         ON l.prim_key = women.prim_key
         AND SUBSTR( l.fieldname, 5, 1 ) = SUBSTR( women.fieldname, 5, 1 ) 
         WHERE l.basicname =  'Q08' 
         AND AES_DECRYPT( l.answertext,  "aaa" ) = 14
         [AND n.state IN ( {state} )] 
         [AND n.district IN ( {district} )]
   GROUP BY n.psu, AES_DECRYPT( l.answertext,  "aaa" )
```

That query should give you a summary of Q08 answers, and their numbers.

You can then make a separate query for PercYearDontKnow. I believe that re-assembling the data afterwards will still be faster than the frankenquery. Alternatively, code the above query as a SQL view, and assemble it into the larger query.

By the way, instead of using `COUNT( AES_DECRYPT( l.answertext,  "aaa" ) )`, you can probably get away with `COUNT(*)`. It means that the decrypt function will be called less often.

Another option for you is to do `SELECT AES_ENCRYPT( "2", "aaa" )` and to use that value as a constant when comparing for Q08. That way, each field does not need to be repeatedly decrypted.

Afterwards, I'd follow the optimization advice given in another answer here, specifically looking at the execution path to see if you need to add indexes.

Comment: Thank you Gustav Bertram . Have incorporated your suggestions

Comment: You're welcome. I think that the biggest improvement you can make is actually the formatting - keep in mind that once you're done, someone else (maybe your future self) will have to read the code again.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly one...my advice:

- [check indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimization-indexes.html) and see what can be done to improve performance
- [check your table structure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-database-structure.html), be sure is the most close the right one
- [check your joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimization-internals.html) and see what can be changed
- **always always** [check execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) for performance monitoring

And of course, do all that on a test enviroment, not production, it can be messy.
Another advice, do one step at a time, check each small modification to be sure the results are still the same. Save results to compare and get the good one at the end.